# Proper syntax for jq while filtering github commit

Tags: jq

I am struggling with the proper jq syntax for pulling out all the names from a curl call that looks like this:

> my  @repo = `curl -s -R -D $tmp_fh_header -u $o_user:$o_auth https://api.github.com/repos/mycompany/$repo/commits| jq '.[].login'`;

In my case, it should report 10 names, but it only comes back with 5 nulls.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the names for the author of the last commits, you can use:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mycompany/$repo/commits | jq '.[].author.login'
```

If you need the names for the committer of the last commits, you can use:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mycompany/$repo/commits | jq '.[].committer.login'
```

or if you need the unique names for that last call:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/mycompany/$repo/commits | jq '[.[].committer.login] | unique'
```

You can use pagination for more/less results as documented in https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination